# why java serversocket has setrecievebuffersize method？

Tags: java, tcp

i know that socket has the setReceiveBufferSize method,but why severSocket has one. you know if accept a connect i will get a socket to deal with the io stuff, so i just care about socket instance, i can set the receiveBuffer. then what work dose the serversocket setReceiveBufferSize do ?

```
 public synchronized void setReceiveBufferSize (int size) throws SocketException {
    if (!(size > 0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative receive size");
    }
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    getImpl().setOption(SocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF, new Integer(size));
    }
```

Comment: The method does exactly what is stated in the API documentation. Why didn't you check there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize%28int%29

so, essentially, it sets a hint for the operating system's tcp stack for adjusting the TCP window size. this is important for retransmissions due to lost packages and optimal settings depend on  network latency, network congestion and type of data transmitted.

see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Receive_Window

for a more detailed discussion

Answer (score 0):

By the time the `ServerSocket` has accepted the `Socket` it is already too late to negotiate a receive buffer size >= 64k, because the TCP window scaling option is negotiated during the initial handshake. So it has to be set on the `ServerSocket` and inherited by the accepted `Sockets`, as stated in the Javadoc.